# Magento database Synchronization

Tags: mysql, magento, synchronization, magento-1.7

Can any Magento or MySQl  experts please guide me to the best way to synchronize the Magento production websites database with development website database.An ideal way of switch over with no data loss.

Magento production is on version 1.6 while the development is on version 1.7 .The development websites database was **backup of the actual production database** after which we have upgraded,  added functionalities, modules, changed design and got rid of core changes which were made by error , part from this  most of the structure for the production and development website database  is  same from categories,products and attributes point of view.[At the moment this lacks last 3 months of transaction) .
Can any one please suggest as what's the best option to go this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1. Dump the production database and restore on a new local instance
2. Connect the new files with the restored database, in order to allow the new extensions to create their tables
3. Dump from the "development" database the tables related to cms_blocks and pages and import in the database at pt.1
4. check that everything is working as expected (check also the admin settings)
5. Dump the database and restore to production

ELSE:
You can try to use software for Database synchronization, as I remember SQLYog was able to do it, but I am not sure it will work (due to the massive amount of foreign keys in the data)